# Core Data to-many relationship filterContentForSearchText with NSPredicate

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, core-data, nspredicate

I have a `xcdatamodeld` that looks like this:
[image]

I have a `UISearchBar` to my `UITableView` with a `Scope` like this:

[image]

I have added the following methods:

```
- (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope{

    [searchResults removeAllObjects];

    if ([scope isEqualToString:@"Name"]){
        NSString *matchString =  [NSString stringWithFormat: @".*\\b%@.*",searchText];
        NSString *predicateString = @"SELF.name MATCHES[cd] %@";
        NSPredicate *predicate =[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: predicateString, matchString];
        searchResults = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[[self.fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects] filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate]];
    }

    if ([scope isEqualToString:@"Ingredient"]){
        NSString *matchString =  [NSString stringWithFormat: @".*\\b%@.*",searchText];
        NSString *predicateString = @"ANY SELF.ingredients.name MATCHES[cd] %@";
        NSPredicate *predicate =[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: predicateString, matchString];
        searchResults = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[[self.fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects] filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate]];
    }

}


- (BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString{
    [self filterContentForSearchText:searchString scope:[[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar scopeButtonTitles] objectAtIndex:[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar selectedScopeButtonIndex]]];
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchScope:(NSInteger)searchOption{
    [self filterContentForSearchText:[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar text] scope:[[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar scopeButtonTitles] objectAtIndex:[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar selectedScopeButtonIndex]]];
    return YES;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    searchResults = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[[fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects] count]];
}
```

**What I want:**

**(1)** When I search a word with scope 'Name' the app displays ALL recipes whose name CONTAINS the word

[image]

**(2)** When I search a word with scope 'Ingredient' the app displays ALL recipes which have the ingredient whose name CONTAINS the word

[image]

The above pictures shows two recipes with name "aglio olio pepe" and "rigatoni sale pepe" and with ingredients (aglio, olio, pepe) and (rigatoni, sale, pepe).

The second search should show both.

What actually works: (1)

**What actually does NOT work: (2)**

**WHY?**

Comment: beside the fact that the way you filter will not scale well, why are you not simply using the predicate like so: `[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY ingredients.name CONTAINS[cd] %@", searchText]`?

Comment: Because I don't want to search for "half" words. Searches like "toni" or "epe" should not give any results (in this way they don't). Otherwise I already tried what you wrote and didn't work.

Comment: @iAndrew: I have tested your predicate `"ANY SELF.ingredients.name MATCHES[cd] %@"` with the search text "pepe" and your data, and it returned *both* objects, as one would expect.

Comment: I can't understand what doesn't work, it's so frustrating. I recognized that it shows the last recipe I added with the ingredient I'm looking for

Comment: the problem is not there, I have to look into my project. Thanks guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing `xcdatamodeled` solves the problem

[image]